# How to get border to cover entire div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border

I am trying to get a border around the container container-body section of my page but it is only covering the top part of my page until I resize. I added a new div and added the id "main-box" for this specific purpose, but the same thing is happening. Code and screenshot included below. What am I missing? I am using bootstrap if that is helpful.

Thanks so much
Eliza

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Small Business HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.header {
  background-color: rgb(42, 94, 142);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
.header h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.first {
  font-size: 90%;
}
.container-body {
  width: 100%;
}
.main-box {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
#no-bullets {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar .nav li a:hover,
.navbar .nav li a:focus,
#cv {
  color: #b29600;
  background: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active >a {
  color: #b29600;
  background: transparent;
  ;
}
#title-text {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
#main-info {
  background-color: rgba(198, 217, 241, 0.3);
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
}
.title-font {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  background: white;
}
#map {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 100px;
}
.active {
  color: rgb(0, 176, 240);
}
.contact-text {
  color: rgba(0, 176, 240, 1);
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 14px;
  ;
  ;
  line-height: 20px;
  ;
  ;
}
#footer-text a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer-background {
  background: rgba(217, 217, 217, .3);
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  body {} .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 1095px) {
  #motto {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 1095px && max-width:1500px) {
  #motto {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .nav li a {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  #logo_small {
    display: block;
  }
  #logo {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media(min-width :1500px) {
  #motto {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container container-body">
  <div class="main-box">
    <div class="header">
      <h1 id="title-text"><span class="first">L</span> A W &nbsp;<span class="first"> O </span>F F I C E S &nbsp; O F <br>
        <span class="first">S </span>A R A H &nbsp; <span class="first">D </span>I A N E &nbsp; <span class="first">M </span>C <span class="first">S </span>H E A</h1>
    </div>
    <h3 id="motto">L &nbsp;E &nbsp;G &nbsp;A &nbsp;L &nbsp; &nbsp; E &nbsp;T &nbsp;H &nbsp;I &nbsp;C &nbsp;S &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;A &nbsp;N &nbsp;D &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;P &nbsp;R &nbsp;O &nbsp;F &nbsp;E &nbsp;S &nbsp;S &nbsp;I &nbsp;O &nbsp;N &nbsp;A &nbsp;L &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;R &nbsp;E &nbsp;S &nbsp;P &nbsp;O &nbsp;N &nbsp;S &nbsp;I &nbsp;B &nbsp;I &nbsp;L &nbsp;I &nbsp;T &nbsp;Y</h3>
    <!-- Heading Row -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Navbar doesn't collapse -->
      <ul id="no-bullets" class="col-md-3">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="index.html" class="active">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="practiceareas.html">PRACTICE AREAS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="biography.html">BIOGRAPHY</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="professional.html">PROFESSIONAL ACTIVITES</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="professional.html"> PUBLICATIONS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
      <div id="main-info" class="col-md-8">
        <h4><strong>Sarah Diane McShea</strong><small> has practiced in the professional responsibility field since 1980.  Her law practice is devoted to advising lawyers and law firms on professional responsibility matters, including</small></h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Advisory ethics opinions
            <br>
          </li>
          <li>Expert witness on legal ethics and attorney discipline issues</li>
          <li>Disqualification and sanctions litigation in federal and state courts</li>
          <li>Risk management for law firms</li>
          <li>Law firm disputes and dissolutions</li>
          <li>Bar admission proceedings</li>
          <li>Disciplinary defense in bar investigations and prosecutions</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

  </div>
  <!-- /main-info -->

</div>
<!-- /container-body -->

<!-- Footer -->
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>2 6 &nbsp; <span class="first2">B</span> R O A D W A Y , &nbsp; <span class="first2">1 8</span> T H &nbsp; <span class="first2">F</span> L O O R
          <br>
          <span class="first2">N</span> E W &nbsp; <span class="first2">Y</span> O R K , &nbsp; <span class="first2">N Y</span> , &nbsp; 1 0 0 0 4
          <br>
          <span class="first2">T</span> E L : 2 1 2 - 6 7 9 -9 0 9 0 &nbsp;
          <br>
        </p>
        <p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p><a class="contact-text email-alert" href="mailto:sdm@mcshealaw.com">s d m @ m c s h e a l a w . c o m</a>
          <br>
          <a class="contact-text" href="#">D I R E C T I O N S</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

  </div>

  <div id="footer-background" class="col-md-12">
    <p id="footer-text">2015 Law Offices of Sarah Diane McShea / Peer Rated AV Preeminent &reg 5.0 out of 5 / 2015 New York Area "Super Lawyer" / Attorney Advertising / <a href="doc/Disclaimer.pdf">Disclaimer</a> / Site Map</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-md-12 -->
</div>


</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but maybe add margin: 0 to body?

Comment: Just to add to that comment - what exactly is the end result that you are going for? It's kind of hard to tell from the wording.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't able to add screenshots that would have helped explain a lot. Basically my border should cover everything on the page except for the footer, but it is only surrounding the header and the "motto" but not the nav bar on the left or the main text. When I resize to make the screen smaller, it jumps down to surround everything on the page, which is why I am confused as it doesn't seem like it's placed wrong but for some reason not recognizing the left navbar and the "main info" divs as being within the "main-box" div when window is large. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear for me, but if you have to make a **border to the body container**, you can use four `fixed` `DIV` elements to do it, each one placed at the 4 edge of the page.

### HTML

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#top, #bottom, #left, #right { position: fixed; }
```

Here is the [working demo](http://jsbin.com/ragoyoyexe/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Read [this post](https://css-tricks.com/body-border/) for full reference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the footer inside the border? You have your `.container-body` and `.main-box` closing off before the footer. Just move them down and your problem is solved.

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Small Business HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.header {
  background-color: rgb(42, 94, 142);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
.header h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.first {
  font-size: 90%;
}
.container-body {
  width: 100%;
}
.main-box {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
#no-bullets {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar .nav li a:hover,
.navbar .nav li a:focus,
#cv {
  color: #b29600;
  background: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active >a {
  color: #b29600;
  background: transparent;
  ;
}
#title-text {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
#main-info {
  background-color: rgba(198, 217, 241, 0.3);
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
}
.title-font {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  background: white;
}
#map {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 100px;
}
.active {
  color: rgb(0, 176, 240);
}
.contact-text {
  color: rgba(0, 176, 240, 1);
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 14px;
  ;
  ;
  line-height: 20px;
  ;
  ;
}
#footer-text a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer-background {
  background: rgba(217, 217, 217, .3);
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  body {} .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 1095px) {
  #motto {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
@media(min-width: 1095px && max-width:1500px) {
  #motto {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .nav li a {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  #logo_small {
    display: block;
  }
  #logo {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media(min-width :1500px) {
  #motto {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container container-body">
  <div class="main-box">
    <div class="header">
      <h1 id="title-text"><span class="first">L</span> A W &nbsp;<span class="first"> O </span>F F I C E S &nbsp; O F <br>
        <span class="first">S </span>A R A H &nbsp; <span class="first">D </span>I A N E &nbsp; <span class="first">M </span>C <span class="first">S </span>H E A</h1>
    </div>
    <h3 id="motto">L &nbsp;E &nbsp;G &nbsp;A &nbsp;L &nbsp; &nbsp; E &nbsp;T &nbsp;H &nbsp;I &nbsp;C &nbsp;S &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;A &nbsp;N &nbsp;D &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;P &nbsp;R &nbsp;O &nbsp;F &nbsp;E &nbsp;S &nbsp;S &nbsp;I &nbsp;O &nbsp;N &nbsp;A &nbsp;L &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;R &nbsp;E &nbsp;S &nbsp;P &nbsp;O &nbsp;N &nbsp;S &nbsp;I &nbsp;B &nbsp;I &nbsp;L &nbsp;I &nbsp;T &nbsp;Y</h3>
    <!-- Heading Row -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Navbar doesn't collapse -->
      <ul id="no-bullets" class="col-md-3">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="index.html" class="active">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="practiceareas.html">PRACTICE AREAS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="biography.html">BIOGRAPHY</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="professional.html">PROFESSIONAL ACTIVITES</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="professional.html"> PUBLICATIONS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
      <div id="main-info" class="col-md-8">
        <h4><strong>Sarah Diane McShea</strong><small> has practiced in the professional responsibility field since 1980.  Her law practice is devoted to advising lawyers and law firms on professional responsibility matters, including</small></h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Advisory ethics opinions
            <br>
          </li>
          <li>Expert witness on legal ethics and attorney discipline issues</li>
          <li>Disqualification and sanctions litigation in federal and state courts</li>
          <li>Risk management for law firms</li>
          <li>Law firm disputes and dissolutions</li>
          <li>Bar admission proceedings</li>
          <li>Disciplinary defense in bar investigations and prosecutions</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

<!-- Footer -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>2 6 &nbsp; <span class="first2">B</span> R O A D W A Y , &nbsp; <span class="first2">1 8</span> T H &nbsp; <span class="first2">F</span> L O O R
              <br>
              <span class="first2">N</span> E W &nbsp; <span class="first2">Y</span> O R K , &nbsp; <span class="first2">N Y</span> , &nbsp; 1 0 0 0 4
              <br>
              <span class="first2">T</span> E L : 2 1 2 - 6 7 9 -9 0 9 0 &nbsp;
              <br>
            </p>
            <p>
          </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <p><a class="contact-text email-alert" href="mailto:sdm@mcshealaw.com">s d m @ m c s h e a l a w . c o m</a>
              <br>
              <a class="contact-text" href="#">D I R E C T I O N S</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

      </div>

      <div id="footer-background" class="col-md-12">
        <p id="footer-text">2015 Law Offices of Sarah Diane McShea / Peer Rated AV Preeminent &reg 5.0 out of 5 / 2015 New York Area "Super Lawyer" / Attorney Advertising / <a href="doc/Disclaimer.pdf">Disclaimer</a> / Site Map</p>
      </div>
  <!-- /.col-md-12 -->
    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- /.main-box -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```